# Add lines to the legend in R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a map in R (`ggplot2` and `sf`) but I can't seem to add transport lines to the legend. I have 4 lines (T1, T2, T3, T4) whose size I can't change either. I also can't manage to add a background map like OSM or a light OSM. I tried several options without success. Here's my code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = Geo_3M) +
  geom_sf(data=T1, color = "blue")+
  geom_sf(data=T2, color = "orange")+
  geom_sf(data=T3, color = "green")+
  geom_sf(data=T4, color = "brown")+
  geom_point(data = tableau_résultat, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, size = nb_endTime, color = categorie)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = couleurs)+
  geom_point(data = Gare, aes(x = lon, y = lat), shape=24, fill="blue") +
  theme(
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  labs(size = "Nb")+
  labs(color = "Duration")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [documentation from `ggplot` for `geom_sf`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html) we find `show.legend = "line"` as well as some other options. Besides, I would recommend pivoting your dataframe to a long version and then using `geom_sf(data = T_long, mapping = aes(color = T_number))` (`T_long` containing the values and `T_number` the name of the column). You can change the color for each line with (I believe) `scale_fill_manual` for each `T_number` in your dataframe.